# Gradle fails to compile with a maven block

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'd like to use a lib [com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) that uses **jitpack** repository, so My `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'

    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
}
```

Until yesterday everything worked good, but now I got a lot of strange errors about this `jitpack`. Tested to remove `com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3` just in a clean project if we add

```
 repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
```

it will fail

Full stack trace:

```
> org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:preFLAV_flavorReleaseBuild' property 'compileManifests' during up-to-date check.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:333)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.createExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:154)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.access$100(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.getCurrentExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:FLAV_flavorReleaseCompileClasspath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:918)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1600(DefaultConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:892)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionVisitorImpl.visitCollection(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitRootElements(AbstractFileCollection.java:234)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitRootElements(CompositeFileCollection.java:185)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultGenericFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultGenericFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:331)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+.
Required by:
    project :app
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainDependencyToComponentIdResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainDependencyToComponentIdResolver.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$DependencyToComponentIdResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:149)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.dependencysubstitution.DependencySubstitutionResolver.resolve(DependencySubstitutionResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.SelectorState.resolveModuleRevisionId(SelectorState.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.EdgeState.resolveModuleRevisionId(EdgeState.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.performSelectionSerially(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:261)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolveEdges(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:226)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:143)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$4.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:483)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:474)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:459)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1700(DefaultConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:901)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:889)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$VersionListResult.process(DynamicVersionResolver.java:428)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$VersionListResult.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver$RepositoryResolveState.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:231)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.findLatestModule(DynamicVersionResolver.java:140)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.findLatestModule(DynamicVersionResolver.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.DynamicVersionResolver.resolve(DynamicVersionResolver.java:88)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ChainedVersionLister$1.visit(ChainedVersionLister.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.listVersionsForAllPatterns(ExternalResourceResolver.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.doListModuleVersions(ExternalResourceResolver.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.access$100(ExternalResourceResolver.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ExternalResourceResolver.java:462)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:345)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.listModuleVersions(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.listModuleVersions(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:111)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.load(MavenMetadataLoader.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenVersionLister$1.visit(MavenVersionLister.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ChainedVersionLister$1.visit(ChainedVersionLister.java:47)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.access$300(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.parseMavenMetadataInfo(MavenMetadataLoader.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.load(MavenMetadataLoader.java:51)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:350)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:340)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to jitpack.io:443 [jitpack.io/104.24.23.62, jitpack.io/104.24.22.62] failed: Read timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:94)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 115 more
```

Comment: where u add the repository in Project level build.gradle or app level

Comment: Could you update your question with what version of Gradle you are using please?

Comment: @ShubhamJain app level of course

Comment: add this `repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    } `
in project label and     `implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'` in app label

Answer (score 2):

I just tested and it works. Make sure you added 
`maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` under allprojects not buildscript

build.gradle(project level)

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(app level)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), you need to do the following:

In your Project level build.gradle: (project/build.gradle)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

In your App level build.gradle: (project/app/build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This library works for me.
here is my gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and here is the dependencies, just look at the mpChart.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.galzaid.whatismybill"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.0'
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.11@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```